# Can't kill SystemUI with activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses

Tags: android

first question here and I am pretty knew to Android development so excuse me.
For part of my app I would like to add a button that can restart the systemui, I am doing this by the following code.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.android.systemui");
        }
```

I have gave the application SU permission with the following code

```
public Process p;

{
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the permission KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES to be able to call this method.

su doesn't play a role here, because you are using android's framework for this operation. If you use busybox to kill the process, than you need su.

Generally, it is not a good idea to kill SystemUI, though.

Comment: I have added the KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES in the Android Manifest, for some reason it seems as though it silently skips from killing com.android.systemui

Answer (score 0):

SystemUI cannot be killed by using Android framework's features. You should use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c killall com.android.systemui"); if you want to kill SystemUI with root. Note that the sereen will go black until SystemUI is restarted soon.